# JSON indexed arrays to javascript indexed arrays

Tags: javascript, json

I have a php file that echoes the following JSON encoded indexed array.

PHP information

The php page has the following header

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

The php echoes the following json indexed array

```
 [
        [
            [17, 28, 1, "z"],
            [28, 31, 6, "b"],
            [8, 29, 6, "b"]
        ],
        [
            [19, 28, 1, "z"],
            [17, 25, 6, "b"],
            [19, 25, 6, "b"],
            [27, 32, 6, "b"],
            [9, 28, 6, "b"]
        ]
    ]
```

I have been pulling my hair out to reproduce it as an indexed javascript array using jquery, i'd prefer to use POST  because there could be a lot of data to pass in the future. All the examples I-ve come across are for small uses of associative arrays and or for immediate output.

JAVASCRIPT attempts

```
$.post('matchEngine.php', 
    function(data){
        var info = data; 
        document.write(info);
        }
    );
```

//output = 17, 28, 1, "z",28, 31, 6, "b",8, 29, 6, "b" etc etc a long list of csv values!

```
$.post('matchEngine.php', 
        function(data){
        var info = $.parseJSON(data); 
        document.write(info);
        }
        );
```

//no output

Desired result

```
var info=  [[[17, 28, 1, "z"],[28, 31, 6, "b"],[8, 29, 6, "b"]],[[19, 28, 1, "z"],[17, 25, 6, "b"],[19, 25, 6, "b"],[27, 32, 6, "b"],[9, 28, 6, "b"]]]
```

Comment: First off, if that's the entire PHP file you have, you're sending some bogus text with the JSON. If there is an opening PHP tag before, you're not sending anything. Should I assume there's a closing PHP tag between the first two lines?

Comment: It-s the echo of the php json_encode if i load just the php in the browser

Comment: Second, `document.write` cannot be used after the document has loaded unless you don't mind your entire web page disappearing. It's best to avoid it completely - you can use `console.log` instead.

Comment: @jan, i know its just for testing

Comment: The `header` call should be interpreted by the server, not sent to the client as-is.

Comment: @jan , yep, i was just trying to show any of the pertinent info from the server side

Comment: @jan, hopefully the edits make things a little clearer!

Comment: I don't understand your goal. What does *"reproduce it as an indexed javascript array"* mean exactly?

Comment: @deceze i-ve added the indexed javascript array that i am trying to create

Comment: If you want the array output as shown above, just JSON-encode it again before displaying.

Comment: The desired result will cause the output as shown by your first attempt.

Comment: Is `document.write` merely your way of *debugging* the values you're getting? If so, it's a *bad* way of debugging; use `console.log` and look at your Javascript console instead. Or are you trying to actually print this `[[...]]` structure into the document?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output for your first code is exactly as expected.

If you convert an array to a string, it will make a comma separated list of the string representation of each item. As the items are arrays, they will also be converted to comma separated strings.

So, `17, 28, 1, "z"` in the output is the string representation of the first inner array, followed by a comma, and the string representation of the next array, and so on. As each level is separated by commas, you can't tell the difference between a nested array and a flat array by looking at the output.

In your second code you are trying to parse the data that was already parsed. That will implicitly convert the array into the string representation, and as that is not valid JSON, you won't get anything back.

To access the data, just use brackets to access the items in the array. For example `data[0]` will return the array `[[17, 28, 1, "z"],[28, 31, 6, "b"],[8, 29, 6, "b"]]`, `data[0][0]` will return the array `[17, 28, 1, "z"]`, and `data[0][0][3]` will return the value `"z"`.

Comment: thanks, but how do i create a variable that holds this array data? since document.write will show me the array and yet I am producing either nothing or csv!

Comment: @Gamemorize `data` *is* that variable! You already have it! You're just looking at it wrong.

Comment: @Gamemorize `document.write(...)` is unable to preserve the array structure by itself. If you want to display the array as JSON, you need to encode it first: `document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(...)` (I refuse to use DW).

Comment: to all! thanks +1, its still twisting my melon and I can-t seem to get to 'work' with the data though... but at least I know that its 'there' in a suitable format!